# DownloadFileAsync vs DownloadFileTaskAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, task, webclient

1. What is the difference of **DownloadFileAsync** and **DownloadFileTaskAsync**?
2. When I should use one instead of another? Any example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General pattern - if you find two methods with names ending `xxxAsync` and `xxxTaskAsync`, then you should generally prefer the `Task` version.

The two versions will exist because the `xxxAsync` version was created before the [Task-based Async Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) (TAP) was introduced, and will be based on an older async pattern.

When introducing TAP methods, the usual recommendation is to suffix the name with `Async` - but that cannot be done when there's already another method that has that same name<sup>1</sup> - so the recommendation then is to suffix with `TaskAsync`.

In this specific case `DownloadFileAsync` is an implementation of the ["Event-based Async Pattern"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw(v=vs.110).aspx) (EAP), which tends to be more awkward to work with. That pattern, itself, superceded the original async pattern within the .NET Framework, which was based on matching `Begin` and `End` prefixed methods and `IAsyncResult`, the [Async Programming Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

<sup>1</sup>In general, of course, you can introduce multiple methods with the same name, provided they have different signatures. But when it comes to the async patterns, an EAP async method and a TAP async method will generally take the same arguments - they'll only differ on their return type. Even if they did vary in their arguments, putting both patterns under exactly the same name would probably cause more confusion.

Comment: .. and for `DownloadFileAsync` you need to add an event handler to the `DownloadFileCompleted` event to know when it's complete, as opposed to just awaiting the Task returned by `DownloadFileTaskAsync`

Comment: @stuartd - I know I'm late to comment on your comment but, yes, of course you do. Because that's the expectation when working with EAP.

Comment: Indeed it is. But anyone looking for the answer to this question most likely doesn't know that.